# Windows 8: Hints, Tips & Tricks?

Tags: discussion, windows-8

Is it possible to have a Windows 8: Hints, Tips & Tricks question on SuperUser, which is kind of like a community wiki (if thats the correct term), where one hint tip or trick is given per answer. As it grows people can search appropriately so as not to duplicate an answer that someone has already given.

Is this a good idea or not really practical ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would be cautious in endorsing these types of questions as they likely to be closed as "Not Constructive":

> As it currently stands, this question is not a good fit for our Q&A format. We expect answers to be supported by facts, references, or specific expertise, but **this question will likely solicit** debate, arguments, **polling, or extended discussion**. If you feel that this question can be improved and possibly reopened, see the FAQ for guidance.

These types of questions lead to TONS of answers, that a user would have to filter through.  Unless the rest of the community disagrees, I would say this isn't a good idea.

Comment: The reason I ask is on Ask Different there is this post http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/400/please-share-your-hidden-os-x-features-or-tips-and-tricks

Comment: Ask Different isn't Super User.  They have their ways and we have ours.  That's not to deny that there are question out there of this nature (even within Super User), but I don't think this type of question will really solicit the quality of answers that we look for here at Super User.

Comment: Thats fine. I thought I better ask anyway :)

Comment: And thank you for asking.  We'd much rather help guide you on what to do here than you get upset or frustrated from us moderating on the main site.  With the amount of moderation that goes on, we can become calloused at times and not help out the new guys too much.

Comment: SU used to have a lot of questions like this, and they've mostly been removed over the years. What you end up with is 5 pages of answers, with lots of repeated tricks, and no real structure. It seems like a good idea but it ends up not being useful because there's too much info to sort through. If you're interested in doing a tips and tricks type thing, you might consider getting suggestions/tip recommendations from people (perhaps via a google docs form or something?) and then writing up a blog post on the [SU Blog](http://blog.superuser.com/) to publish them all in a nice, cohesive format.

Comment: @nhinkle Thanks for the idea, I didnt know there was a SU Blog - so much to learn.

Comment: @KronoS Its fine, I'm better at answering questions, than asking them - its better for me to clarify here - wish I had done that previously :)

Comment: @Simon if you're interested in blogging ping either me or nhinkle in the [SU.Blog chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/356/super-user-blog-editor-room) and we'll get you setup.

Comment: @KronoS Ok Thankyou v. much I'll keep it in mind

Comment: Gack!!!  A question with 123 answers?  How the heck is anyone supposed to derive anything useful from that?  "Ask Different"?  They certainly are.  Glad I'm not there...

Comment: @killermist Your funny :)